# Compare two arrays in Ruby and create a third array of elements

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two arrays, `array1` and `array2`.  I need to compare both of these arrays and I want to create a third array, `array3`, whereby it shows the elements that are in `array2`, that are not in `array1`.

This is what I have so far:

```
my_buckets = Model.select("DISTINCT bucket").where(["my_id = ?", params[:user]])

all_buckets = Model.select("DISTINCT bucket").collect { |x| x.bucket }.uniq.compact

buckets_not_in_my_buckets = Model.select("DISTINCT bucket").where(["bucket NOT IN (?)", my_buckets]).collect { |x| x.bucket }.uniq.compact
```

For some reason, the `buckets_not_in_my_buckets` is always returning an empty array (`[]`).  Is there a better way to approach this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
buckets_not_in_my_buckets = all_buckets - my_buckets
```

I'm assuming that you have the `eql?` operator on your buckets object working how you'd like.

Please see the [Array docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-2D) for more detail.

Comment: Unfortunately, the buckets_not_in_my_buckets is returning all buckets (exactly the same elements as all_buckets), not the difference between the two buckets. What do you mean when you say "have the eql? operator on your buckets object working"?  Maybe that's the problem. Thoughts?

Comment: OK, figured out the issue.  The my_buckets array had extra data which all_buckets array did not have so all_buckets - my_buckets did not execute properly.  I added the following to the my_buckets statement so that it only contained the bucket id (no extra data) and everything worked perfectly: .collect { |x| x.basket }.uniq.compact